# Why can't polymorphic derived classes be nested inside the base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, inner-classes

For example, I tried to do something like this:

```
class Animal {
public:
    virtual const char *says() const = 0;

    static Animal *makeLion() { return new Lion(); }
    static Animal *makeTiger() { return new Tiger(); }
    static Animal *makePig() { return new Pig(); }

private:
    class Lion : public Animal { // error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Animal’
    public:
        virtual const char *says() const
        {
            return "roar";
        }
    };

    class Tiger : public Animal { // error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Animal’
    public:
        virtual const char *says() const
        {
            return "meow";
        }
    };

    class Pig : public Animal { // error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Animal’
    public:
        virtual const char *says() const
        {
            return "That\'s all Folks!";
        }
    };
};
```

The compiler complains that `Animal` is an incomplete type. But why is `Animal` an incomplete type, if the inner class definitions are not needed to define the outer class itself (since no non-static variables of the inner class types are declared by value in the outer class)?

Is there a way around this or a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: A class is not complete until you reach the closing `};`.

Comment: The class is not complete until it is, well, complete. And what exactly is your motivation for trying to do this?

Comment: @NathanOliver: That's not completely true. You can declare static members of `Animal` within `Animal`. As far as I know, inner classes are treated as static.

Comment: @Matt That is a special case.  It is still a incomplete type until the definition that is done outside the class once it is complete.  A class itself is never considered complete until you see the `};`.

Comment: @Matt: It is complete true. You can declare static members, but not define them. A declaration does not require a complete type, but a definition does.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Well, I think a definition of a `constexpr` `static` data member counts as a definition. This thing is a mess. I have never understood the reasons for the requirements & limitations.

Comment: Why want to emulate Java's broken semantics in C++?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A class is not complete until the closing brace `}` of the class definition.

Re “is there a way around this”, you can do things like this:

```
struct A
{
    struct B;
};

struct A::B
    : A
{};
```

But it's not a common pattern. I can't remember ever having seen it.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted (since `struct B` can be made a private member of `struct A`)!

Answer (score 10):

> Is there a way around this or a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Don't use nested classes. Just move the derived classes out of `Animal`.

---

On a separate note, having functions

```
static Animal *makeLion() { return new Lion(); }
static Animal *makeTiger() { return new Tiger(); }
static Animal *makePig() { return new Pig(); }
```

in `Animal` is a symptom of poor design. A base class should, as much as possible, be agnostic of classes derived from it.

---

Here's a suggestion for a cleaner interface and implementation:

Animal.h:

```
namespace AnimalsNamespace
{
   // The base class
   class Animal
   {
      public:
         virtual const char *says() const = 0;
   };


   // Functions to construct objects of various sub-types of Animal.
   // Moving these out of Animal and putting them in the namespace makes
   // Animal a little bit cleaner.

   Animal* makeLion();
   Animal* makeTiger();
   Animal* makePig();
}
```

Animal.cpp:

```
namespace AnimalsNamespace
{
   class Lion : public Animal
   {
      public:
         virtual const char *says() const
         {
            return "roar";
         }
   };

   class Tiger : public Animal
   {
      public:
         virtual const char *says() const
         {
            return "meow";
         }
   };

   class Pig : public Animal
   {
      public:
         virtual const char *says() const
         {
            return "That\'s all Folks!";
         }
   };

   Animal* makeLion() { return new Lion(); }
   Animal* makeTiger() { return new Tiger(); }
   Animal* makePig() { return new Pig(); }
}
```

Comment: I want the classes to be private. Also, ever heard of the factory pattern? There's no reason a the base class can't be a factory for its limited set of derived classes.

Comment: When you say private, do you mean hidden from users?

Comment: Well I want them to be effectively hidden, without having to do anything wacky.

Comment: @Matt I would put them in a detail/implementation name space.  SOP is anything in a namespace like that can be changed and if you use it, it is your fault.

Comment: @Matt Put them in a .cpp file.

Comment: @RSahu The functions in the header should be simply declared, not defined

Comment: Your new suggestion is something that I was considering, and is probably the best solution in the end, but it shouldn't be a requirement to do what I wanted to do. Thanks for you input anyway!

Comment: @jaggedSpire: There is such a thing as overseparation of concerns. Also, are they not static?

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to put definition of Lion, Tiger, Pig in function scope:

```
class Animal {
public:
    virtual ~Animal() = default;
    virtual const char *says() const = 0;

    static std::unique_ptr<Animal> makeLion()
    {
        class Lion : public Animal
        {
        public:
            virtual const char *says() const override
            {
                return "roar";
            }
        };
        return std::make_unique<Lion>();
    }
    static std::unique_ptr<Animal> makeTiger() {
        class Tiger : public Animal
        {
        public:
            virtual const char *says() const override
            {
                return "meow";
            }
        };
        return std::make_unique<Tiger>();
    }
    static std::unique_ptr<Animal> makePig() {
        class Pig : public Animal
        {
        public:
            virtual const char *says() const override
            {
                return "That\'s all Folks!";
            }
        };
        return std::make_unique<Pig>();
    }
};

int main() {    
    std::cout << Animal::makeLion()->says() << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/ETkSyL).

Comment: I considered that, but then any other derived class features would not be accessible from the base class. And you wouldn't be able to make multiple factory methods for the same class.

Answer (score -1):

Bad design.  Making an object should not be done in Animal class.  Consider redesigning the classes like:

```
class Animal
{
public:
    virtual const char* says() const = 0;
};

class Lion : public Animal
{
public:
    virtual const char *says() const
    {
        return "roar";
    }
};

class Tiger : public Animal
{
public:
    virtual const char *says() const
    {
        return "meow";
    }
};

class Pig : public Animal
{
public:
    virtual const char *says() const
    {
        return "That\'s all Folks!";
    }
};
```

And then use like this:

```
Animal* p = new Pig;
cout << p->says() << endl;
```

Otherwise, you have to add makeXXX() functions every time you add a new kind.

Comment: If that was what I wanted to do, I would have done that.